# VB.NET Returning sum hours of datetimepicker

Tags: vb.net, date, datetime, sum, datetimepicker

I have a SELECT that returns a column in datagridview called date and time of datetimepicker and also a column with the flag "input" or "output". I want to return a result with the sum of hours of datetimepicker with the flag "input" and another sum to the flag " ouput ".
Could you help me guys?

Cheers....

Comment: You *really* want to sum the hour of the day on a bunch of dates?  You should also read [Ask] and take the [Tour].

Comment: For example : an employee to work at 08:00 am and left at 11:00 am , 1:00 pm and returned the left 05:00 pm . I want to make this day selection from 01 til 20 .

Comment: what? can get your point. an employee take a work till 8 - 11 am? then 11am - 1pm? vacant time? then resume in 1-5pm? hmm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But anyway try this to get the sum of time in hours or minutes.

```
Dim FirstIn As String = CDate(dtp1.value.date).ToString("HH:mm") 'try with or without cdate.
Dim FirstOut As String = CDate(dtp2.value.date).ToString("HH:mm") 'try with or without cdate.

Dim elapsedTime As TimeSpan = DateTime.Parse(FirstOut).Subtract(DateTime.Parse(FirstIn))
Dim elapsedMinutesText As String = elapsedTime.Minutes.ToString()
Dim elapsedHrsText As String = elapsedTime.Hours.ToString * 60
Dim totalMinute As String = CInt(elapsedMinutesText) + CInt(elapsedHrsText)
'then try to isert it to txtbox or message box to see the result.
'but now you can get the minutes and total hours of it.
```

Hope this it what you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot Muj, that's it... =D